# setStreamMute(STREAM_RING) muting text to speech android

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

I am trying to speak some text. muting STREAM_RING has also muted Text to speech for some odd reason. I have searched internet but I guess no one had this issue before so I couldn't find an answer. Here is my code:

```
int volume=0;

    if(state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Inside", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if(incomingNumber != null)
        {
            volume= audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);


            audioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, true);
            audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, 0, AudioManager.FLAG_ALLOW_RINGER_MODES);
            tts.speak(incomingNumber, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "speak number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


        if(state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE)
        {
            audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, volume, AudioManager.FLAG_ALLOW_RINGER_MODES);
            audioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, you can use this idea, on receiving the call rather than muting the Ring Stream you can set the ringtone as silent temporarily and accomplish your task, then you can restore it if you really need to. To set ringtone use System.Settings class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int mRingerMode;

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "INCOMING CALL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

if(state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING)
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Inside", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    if(incomingNumber != null)
    {
        mRingerMode = audioManager.getRingerMode();
                        audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
        new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                HashMap<String, String> myHashRender = new HashMap<String, String>();
                myHashRender.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_STREAM, 
                        String.valueOf(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL));
                tts.speak(incomingNumber, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, myHashRender);
            }
        }).start();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "speak number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    if(state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE)
    {
        audioManager.setRingerMode(mRingerMode);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Was onInit called when you call tts.speak?

Comment: Comment out the line audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT); and see if tts.speak will work.

Comment: then it just rings. TTs doesn't speak

Comment: I have posted the code. See if it has something wrong. I am initializing tts and telephonemanager in onStartCommand()

Comment: Was the toast that you have in onInit shown before you called tts.speak? you can log int value = tts.speak to see if it is a success or failure.

Comment: It is returning 0, SUCCESS

Comment: That is strange, I have no problem with the code above in my app. I called tts.speak in a thread though. Let me edit my answer.

Comment: weird I opened another emulator and it started working. BTW can I have your email or something cuz I need a good instructor like you :D

Comment: Change to the code below to see if it works: HashMap<String, String> myHashRender = new HashMap<String, String>(); myHashRender.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_STREAM, 
       String.valueOf(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL)); tts.speak(incomingNumber, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, myHashRender);

Comment: You can get my email by clicking on my name.

Comment: Can you explain what is this hashmap for?

Comment: The hashmap is to set the type of stream and/or the utterance id.

Comment: I mean if I don't use it, although tts is speaking but it is mute. hmm ok. So, you have changed the stream for audio of tts. But is it really necessary to use AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL .

Comment: You should not need to set stream at all, unless a bluetooth headset is active. I never tested in emulator so I do not know why you have to set stream in emulator. You can try to set other stream, my guess is they probably also work.

Comment: you are talking about AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL that it is used for bluetooth headset right? BTW where did you learn all this stuff? Android documentation doesn't elaborate when to use stuff for most of the things

Comment: In my app, I only need to set STREAM_VOICE_CALL when bluetooth headset is on. Otherwise, speaking a name or phone number when receiving CALL_STATE_RINGING is working fine without having to set a stream type. Well, I just play around when something does not work.